# PWM solar charger Audible noise

Tags: solar-cell

I am trying to develop a solar PWM charger controller for LEAD ACID battery based on NMOS high-side switching as you can see in the picture below.
[image]
NMOS Driver

the controller works fine most of the time, but when the voltage reaches the battery setpoint voltage (13.8V in my case, and 100W solar panel), the controller starts regulating with audible noise (freq = 50HZ).

is this normal ?? if it is not how can solve it??.
and if it is, do all commercial PWM controllers have the same issue ??.

Comment: My first guess is you need hysteresis as the controller is hunting at this setpoint. What's more interesting to me is what part of the circuit is making audible noise? And what does this noise sound like?

Comment: Faint buzzing noise when the Mosfet starts switching

Comment: Where does "DRIVER" node come from? And do you know if that signal is is oscillating? If you hold "DRIVER " high, does the buzzing stop?

Comment: The DRIVER node is connected to microcontroller pin (configured as PWM  output in my case), if the driver node is held static (either on or off) the buzzing stops, but if I start the pwm with 50 hz with any duty cycle it starts buzzing